# What is causing this DB2 for i SQL oddity?

Tags: sql, cursor, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We've had an ongoing, intermittent problem with an SQLRPGLE program which is failing to load data to the screen. A colleague has just figured out how to reliably reproduce it so I've been investigating in the debugger.

The program opens an SQL cursor to a remote system to populate a subfile and if the user presses F5 it closes the cursor and re-opens it. Under certain circumstances this fails in an interesting way.

The discovered repeatable process is to run the function first, exit, then issue STRSQL (which shows the remote connection still active) and CONNECT RESET. Then quit back to the command line and start the function anew. THIS WORKS on first display AND after pressing F5 ONCE. But on a second press of F5 the cursor gets weird and the program cannot load the data.

Here's the sequence of events I ran in the debugger and the SQLSTATE value after each key SQL function. I checked the first FETCH of each display just as a sanity check. The connects are reconnecting (probably unnecessarily) to the remote system each time.

```
Action          SQLSTATE    Meaning
Initial connect 0           OK
Open cursor     0           OK
First fetch     0           OK
F5 pressed      
Close cursor    0           OK
Reconnect       8002        Already connected
Open cursor     0           OK
First fetch     0           OK
F5 pressed
Close cursor    0           OK
Reconnect       8002        Already connected
Open cursor     0           OK
First fetch     0           OK
Exit program            
Close cursor    0           OK
STRSQL CONNECT      
Reconnect       8002        Already connected
Open cursor     0           OK
First fetch     0           OK
F5 pressed      
Close cursor    0           OK
Reconnect       8002        Already connected
Open cursor     0           OK
First fetch     0           OK
F5 pressed      
Close cursor    0           OK
Reconnect       8002        Already connected
Open cursor     24502       Already open
First fetch     24501       Cursor not open
```

The loop of pressing F5 works indefinitely before the CONNECT RESET is run.

After exiting the function, returning to it still shows the empty list (i.e. the cursor problem still exists) but if the program's activation group is reclaimed, then the first display and first F5 works again, but a second F5 causes the cursor issue once more.

I tried running RUNSQL SQL('CONNECT RESET') and this failed saying a commitment boundary had not been reached. It's not updating any files so not sure how that can be the issue. We did find that running a COMMIT in STRSQL right before the CONNECT reset does cure the problem, but only temporarily like reclaiming the activation group does.

We've also tried setting commitment control to *NONE on the module and having Close SQL Cursor set to *ENDMOD but neither seems to make any difference.

We sure would appreciate any suggestions on what else to look at!

Comment: What version and release?  Are you reasonably current on PTFs?

Comment: V6R1M1 and yes, reasonably current on PTFs.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is open means the module never ended and closed the cursor.
The sqlrpgle program had to of aborted on something.

data decimal error, result of select more than one row, field too big for insert or update.

Best practice for sql errors is a dump command any time the sqlcode is negative.

```
if sqlcode < 0 
    dump
endif
```

Hot fix close before opening the cursor.  But remember there is still a reason your program is exiting that has to be fixed.

```
close mycursor;
open mycursor;
```

Comment: As shown in the list of actions, when the program was exited, the cursor was successfully closed.

Comment: I will add in the test for SQLCODE < 0 and dump, but please note that the SQL fails but the program does NOT currently crash. It simply gets no records from a fetch (because of the cursor issue) and therefore happily displays an empty subfile.

In the repeated F5 cycle (without issuing the external CONNECT), the cursor is repeatedly closed and re-opened with no problems. Similarly, without introducing the CONNECT externally, we can repeatedly exit and re-run the program and the problem does not occur.

Comment: so try using a connect reset if it only fails after introducing the connect.

Comment: Interestingly, doing that causes the problem to occur if I exit the function and immediately run it again. However, it is fixed if I reclaim the QILE activation group and try again.

Comment: Tricky for us to discuss. `As shown in the list of actions...` Unfortunately, that is **not shown**; instead just a text constant **(`Exit program`)** is what is shown. We know that because `it is fixed if I reclaim the QILE activation group`. That is, there is almost certainly a **RETURN** of some kind that is executed, but the program isn't quite "exited". The program is still activated because ending the AG "fixes" that problem. Simply leaving (returning from) a program isn't quite the same as "exiting" the program when the controlling AG isn't reclaimed.

Comment: Right after the exit line is a close line with a return code of 0. It didn't make sense to me to put it before the exit as then it had no context. The program mainline is a DO loop that exits when *INLR is on. I'm no expert on activation groups but it was my understanding if *INLR is on the program has exited.

Even if it was a return issue, I still cannot make sense of the last two events. "You can't open the cursor because it is already open. You can't use the cursor because it isn't open." This happens ONLY on the 3rd loop of the program. Something is out of step in managing the cursor.

Comment: Having *INLR *ON/*OFF isn't especially relevant to a cursor, though pre-compile options can help to sync them up.

Answer (score 0):

While I still do not understand how the final two events can ever be valid in sequence, I have found a way to stop the CONNECT (external or otherwise) from being a problem.

On the CRTSQLRPGI command there is a parameter:

```
RDB connect method . . . . . . .   *DUW          *DUW, *RUW
```

The help text for *RUW made me think it was worth a try:

```
*RUW                                                                   
CONNECT (Type 1) semantics are used to support remote unit of work.
Consecutive CONNECT statements result in the previous connection   
being disconnected before a new connection is established.
```

I found that `RDBCNNMTH(*RUW)`, combined with `COMMIT(*NONE)`, stops the problem.

I consider this a workaround, but a solid one.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound simple... when you press F5, the *IN05 should be off, pressing the key turns it *ON.  That action should activate whatever you're doing.  -WHAT IF-  something in the process loop is stepping on *IN05 leaving it *ON now(presuming you turn it off right as the function fires off)so when it rolls back around, the connection is already established. Just adding an idea because it really sounds like your SQL is solid.

Comment: Interesting thinking, thanks.

I've run your theory over in my head several times but I still cannot get past the contradiction of the last two actions – which show the cursor to both be open and not open with no (SQL) actions in between.